# How to store an Intervention image in gridfs/mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, streaming, gridfs, intervention

In my application there is a call which might request a resized version of the image. In the case when it is resized I want to store the resized version long-term onto gridfs, exactly like the other images.

I can easily resize the image and return it using Intervention (http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction) however it seems to be that it's not possible to store the resized image to the DB without saving it to a temporary file.

In particular this fails:

```
$bucket = DB::getMongoDB()->selectGridFSBucket();
$stream = $bucket->openDownloadStreamByName($name);
$document = $bucket->getFileDocumentForStream($stream);
$metadata = $document['metadata']->getArrayCopy();
$file = stream_get_contents($stream);
$img = Image::cache(function($image) use ($file){
    $image->make($file);
}, 60, true);
$img->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
    $constraint->upsize();
});
$bucket->uploadFromStream($randomName, $img, ['metadata' => $metadata]);
```

The call to `uploadFromStream` fails saying: `Expected $source to have type "resource" but found "Intervention\Image\CachedImage"`.

Trying to change:
$bucket->uploadFromStream($randomName, $img, ['metadata' => $metadata]);

to:

```
$bucket->uploadFromStream($randomName, $img->stream('png'), ['metadata' => $metadata]);
```

Leads to the same error only that the type changes from `Intevention\Image\CachedImage` to `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream`.

Now I *could* do:

```
$img->save('/tmp/test.png')
$stream = fopen('/tmp/test.png')
$bucket->uploadFromStream($randomName, $stream, ['metadata' => $metadata]);
```

but this is abysmally bad because:

1. it has a race condition. I would need to ensure the filename used is unique otherwise it might be overwritten
2. it writes to disk which means it's going to be way slower than just using an in-memory stream
3. it writes to disk which means it deteriorates more. Consider that this write is completely useless so I'd avoid using it. It can be triggered quite often.

So, is there a way to save the resized image to GridFS **without** passing throught the disk?

Comment: Do you have  a stream for the image data ?

Comment: @D.SM My code is as above. The point is I obtain an image, resize it and I want to save this resized version which is an instance of `Intervention\Image\CachedImage`. So that's what I have. The issue is that it seems like the `stream` method of intervention returns a Psr7 stream instead of a resource.

Comment: I suggest looking at intervention & mongodb docs to figure out the common or most common stream type they support, and updating your question with findings.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: you can obtain the binary data as a string using `$img->response()->content()` and then instead of using `uploadFromStream` you can use `openUploadStream` and write the data.

The full working solution would be:

```
$bucket = DB::getMongoDB()->selectGridFSBucket();
$stream = $bucket->openDownloadStreamByName($name);
$document = $bucket->getFileDocumentForStream($stream);
$metadata = $document['metadata']->getArrayCopy();
$file = stream_get_contents($stream);
$img = Image::cache(function($image) use ($file){
    $image->make($file);
}, 60, true);
$img->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
    $constraint->upsize();
});
$stream = $bucket->openUploadStream($randomName, ['metadata' => $metadata]);
fwrite($stream, $img->response()->content());
fclose($stream);
```